# php session/ info not displaying

Tags: php, session

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['makeFile'])){
$fileName = $_SESSION['firstname']."_".$_SESSION['lastname'];
$newFileName = "users/".$fileName.".txt";

$file = fopen($newFileName, "w");
fwrite($file, $_SESSION['firstname'] . "\n");
fwrite($file, $_SESSION['lastname'] . "\n");
fwrite($file, $_SESSION['age'] . "\n");
fwrite($file, $_SESSION['streetaddrs'] . "\n");
fwrite($file, $_SESSION['postalcode'] . "\n");
fclose($file);


}

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Success</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>First Name: <?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?></p>
<p>Last Name: <?php echo $_SESSION['lastname']; ?></p>
<p>Age: <?php echo $_SESSION['age']; ?></p>
<p>Street Address: <?php echo $_SESSION['streetaddrs']; ?></p>
<p>Postal Code: <?php echo $_SESSION['postalcode']; ?></p>
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="makeFile">SAVE DATA</button>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

When my form is submitted and redirected to this page after filling in the info from the form. The problem is at this screen saveData.php no content is displayed. Any help?

Comment: do you have anything that looks like `$_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];` etc? anywhere?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: In my form.php i have this:

if(count($errors) == 0){
     $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
     $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
     $_SESSION['age'] = $age;
     $_SESSION['streetaddrs'] = $streetaddrs;
     $_SESSION['postalcode'] = $postalcode;
    header("Location: saveData.php");
    exit();
   }

Comment: Do a print_r($_SESSION);